# How to model product ratings in Stan

Tags: bayesian, stan

Hi I've been recently introduced to Bayesian Analysis, and Stan.

As a practice problem I was hoping to to model what is most likely average rating that a product will receive. 
By product ratings I mean and integer distribution with values bounded to [1,2,3,4,5].

Initially i thought that product ratings will be best described by multinomial distribution but I see in Stan's documentation that it accepts just one parameter `theta` which I cannot find information on on the web, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) for example says that this distribution is described by `p` and `N`.

So my question is what would be an appropriate distribution to use here?

See bellow for my STAN model so far:

```
data {
  int<lower=1> N;
  int[N] ratings;
}
parameters {
  real mean;
}
model {
  ratings ~ multinomial(mean);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be best to model such an outcome as *ordinal* (usually with either the standard logistic or standard normal CDF as the mapping function). There in an example in section 9.8 of the [Stan User's Manual](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.16.0/stan-reference-2.16.0.pdf). However, if you are just starting out with Stan and estimating simple models such as this one, it is often better to use the `stan_polr` function in the **rstanarm** R package or the `brm` function in the **brms** R package, which both use Stan to estimate ordinal models using only R syntax rather than Stan syntax.